# get notfication when message marked as read in android

Tags: android, service, sms, contentobserver

I am a bit new to android I am developing an app that listen to URL "content://sms/" and notify me when any new SMS marked as read ( or any operation done on the SMS tables on DB)

I want get notification even if the app isn't runing 
I tried the content observer but it works only once. can some one guide me who to get my requirment done ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want get notification even if the app isn't runing

This is not possible.

Comment: Its possible I did it !

Comment: @AhmadSaadFares: If you "did it", then why are you asking how to do it?

Comment: I did it after asking.  
check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712660/contentobserver-works-only-for-insert-and-delete-but-not-for-an-update

Comment: Your app is running. It is using a `ContentObserver`. That works, so long as your app is running. In your question, you wrote "I want get notification even if the app isn't runing". *That* is not possible.

Comment: no you just need to run the app once so the service started so it will keep working even if the app is off

Comment: If the service is running, then the app is running. The *activity* may have been destroyed or in the background.